# Run a function after push notification

Tags: ios, ipad, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, helpshift

I'm developing an iOS app for iPad. I'm using Push notifications with a service called HelpShift. I'd like to run a piece of code when the users taps the notification. It actually works when the app is active, but when it's background or inactive, it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

if ([[userInfo objectForKey:@"origin"] isEqualToString:@"helpshift"]) {

    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];

    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {           

        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You were answered in HelpShift"
                                                            message:@"Hello"
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Show", nil];
        [alertView show];

    } if (state== UIApplicationStateBackground) {

        UIViewController *vc = self.window.rootViewController;
        [[Helpshift sharedInstance] handleNotification:userInfo withController:vc];            

         [self showHelpShift];

    } if (state == UIApplicationStateInactive) {

        UIViewController *viewController =
        [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                   bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"home"];

        [[Helpshift sharedInstance] handleNotification:userInfo withController:viewController];


    }        
   }
 }


 - (void) showHelpShift {
     UIViewController *vc = self.window.rootViewController;
     [[Helpshift sharedInstance] showSupport:vc];
  }

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

  if (buttonIndex == 1){
    UIViewController *vc = self.window.rootViewController;
    [[Helpshift sharedInstance] showSupport:vc];}
 }
```

So as you can see, the problem is that the [self showHelpShift] doesn't get called or it gets called to early.

Comment: The notification comes in the dictionary passed into thevapplicationDidLaunch message. The above message is not sent at launch.

Comment: So? What do I have to code?

Comment: So you implemented push notifiations, but never read Apple's excellent guide on it? Open the "Local Notifications and Push Notifications" guide and read the section on "Handling Local and Remote Notifications".

Answer (score 2):

Implement `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and look for the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey` key in the `launchOptions` dictionary.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I've tried UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey but the app crashes...